# Getting encoded output when I print hindi text from a tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm using [this](https://www.cfilt.iitb.ac.in/iitb_parallel/) corpus for an NLP task. When I read the file and store the hindi and english lines into separate lists, I get string literal outputs like so:

```
def extract_lines(fp):
    return [line.strip() for line in open(fp).readlines()]

inp,target = extract_lines(train_hi),extract_lines(train_en)

sample: ['अपने अनुप्रयोग को पहुंचनीयता व्यायाम का लाभ दें', 'एक्सेर्साइसर पहुंचनीयता अन्वेषक'] ['Give your application an accessibility workout', 'Accerciser Accessibility Explorer']
```

I then create a tensorflow dataset using the two lists:

```
buffer_size = len(inp)
batch_size = 64

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((inp,target)).shuffle(buffer_size)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
```

The output I get from

```
for input_sample,target_sample in dataset.take(1):
    print(input_sample)
```

is something like:

tf.Tensor(
[b'\xe0\xa4\xb5\xe0\xa5\x8d\xe0\xa4\xaf\xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa5\x8d\xe0\xa4\xa4\xe0\xa4\xbf\xe0\xa4\xaf\xe0\xa5\x8b\xe0\xa4\x82\xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa5\x80 \xe0\xa4\x95\xe0\xa5\x8b\xe0\xa4\x9f\xe0\xa4\xbf\xe0\xa4\xaf\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\x81'

I'm pretty new to dealing with text data (especially in tensorflow), what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tensorflow converts all unicode strings such as the Hindi text to `utf-8` by default. Check this [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/guide/unicode) for more details. If you want to view your data, you can decode the encoded string tensors like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def extract_lines(fp):
    return [line.strip() for line in fp]

inp,target = extract_lines(['अपने अनुप्रयोग को पहुंचनीयता व्यायाम का लाभ दें', 'एक्सेर्साइसर पहुंचनीयता अन्वेषक'] ),extract_lines(['Give your application an accessibility workout', 'Accerciser Accessibility Explorer'])

buffer_size = len(inp)
batch_size = 1

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((inp,target)).shuffle(buffer_size)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

for x, y in dataset:
  print("".join([chr(i) for i in tf.strings.unicode_decode(x, 'utf-8').to_tensor()[0]]), y)
```

```
एक्सेर्साइसर पहुंचनीयता अन्वेषक tf.Tensor([b'Accerciser Accessibility Explorer'], shape=(1,), dtype=string)
अपने अनुप्रयोग को पहुंचनीयता व्यायाम का लाभ दें tf.Tensor([b'Give your application an accessibility workout'], shape=(1,), dtype=string)
```

But note that as soon as the Hindi-text is converted to `tf` tensors, it will be `utf-8` encoded.

Comment: I wonder if this encoding/decoding problem will affect the inner layers (e.g. Input > TextVectorise > Embedding > LSTM ...) or is it just a presentation/printing problem?!